# How to divide trigonometric ratios using identities?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$$
We know:
$$\frac{1-\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}}{1+\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}}$$
Now what? Flip denominator and times numerator?
Which equals ???
Please help - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$
\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{1-\tan^2 x}{\sec^2 x} = \cos^2x - \sin^2x 
$$

But going from your point of view
$$
\frac{1-\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}}{1+\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}}= \frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}}{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}}\frac{\cos^2-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}=\\
\frac{\cos^2-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}
$$
then use the fact
$$
\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1
$$
Dividing through by $\cos^2x$ and knowing that $\frac{1}{\cos x} =\sec x$ will lead to the first identity.

Comment: You can simplify with `$=\cos 2x$`.

Comment: Thank you for quick response but can you "dumb it down" a little and not skip any steps.  How do we know tan^2x+1=sec^2x? Thanks

Comment: @bernard yup. But I wasn't sure how far he wanted to take it. I just wanted to show him the removal of the denominator.

Comment: that is a standard identity but I will update.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still confused - must need more coffee!